# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on startup after installing nvidia-390

Tags: ubuntu, boot, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I installed nvidia-390 drivers on my brand new Ubuntu 18.04 installation and now it freezes during the boot screen that appears before the login screen.

I solved the problem by entering recovery mode, update grub ( which enables read-write mode ) and then continue to boot.

However I'd like not to have to enter recovery mode every time I boot my machine. Is there any real solution to this problem?

I'm on an Asus x370 Pro Prime motherboard and my GPU is a GTX Geforce 1070 Ti.

Things I have already done:

- Secure Boot is already disabled both in BIOS and also through
  mokutil.
- Replaced 'quiet splash' by 'quiet splash nomodeset' at
  /etc/default/grub

Comment: You could check /var/log/Xorg.0.log for any "(EE)"  error lines.

Comment: No (EE) lines were found at all. https://gist.github.com/ruanchaves/0449abf27f1a3c0a726714118d4368b6

Comment: When it's "frozen", can you still switch to console  (CTRL-ALT-F1) ?   I would remove the nouveau driver.   Does lsmod show nvidia or nouveau?

Comment: lsmod shows only nvidia and no nouveau. As for the console, I'll tell you in a few minutes.

Comment: Xorg is still loading the nouveau driver, "apt-get remove" it perhaps.  Did you follow any installation guide?  I'm asking because of the "nomodeset".

Comment: The "nomodeset" was a later fix, it wasn't on the installation guide for nvidia-390.

Comment: Ctrl-alt-f1 doesn't work after it gets stuck at the logo screen.

Comment: I also disabled nouveau driver and it had no effect. https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver

Comment: No, as the kernel driver wasn't loaded anyhow.  But Xorg is loading its nouveau driver, so I'd remove that one.

Comment: Which installation guide did you follow?   https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux ?

Comment: I followed this one, it's very simple. http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

Comment: No mention of "update-initramfs -u" in your guide?  What does "lspci | grep VGA" give you?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It gives me : 28:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 (rev a1)

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes, the "update-initramfs -u" command wasn't mentioned, although I have already executed it while trying to disable nouveau.

Comment: One last try, does "lsmod | grep nvidia" give you the same result as here: http://linuxbsdos.com/2017/06/11/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-10-17-04/ ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Sort of. (I'm on a Ryzen 7 1700 ). https://gist.github.com/ruanchaves/0455a00048e3419bea21c38afc1e0d1f

Comment: One more test for the "frozenness":  can you connect to your system from another device when you have the blackout?  You'd need some server running to be able to test that, sshd would be handy.  Or, can you do a clean shutdown by pushing the power button?  Would also prove your system is still alive, only not responding to the keyboard.   BTW, your system makes me jealous anyhow, just last night I was looking for such a config.

Comment: I've already solved the problem. https://superuser.com/a/1333437/916782 There may be a true solution out there, maybe downgrading from nvidia-390. I bought this system for deep learning, so taken in this context it's just the bare minimum you need to actually run anything real.

Answer (score 1):

I've already solved the problem by doing something that's quite hacky, but it worked. If you boot on text mode and then automatically jump to graphical mode then the problem is gone.

I set text mode as the default boot mode ( `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` ) and then you can set up the command `systemctl start graphical.target` to automatically run right after startup, or manually run it on text mode every time you need a graphical interface.

After that you can edit your grub files to disable authentication either in text or graphical mode or otherwise you'll have to authenticate twice.

Comment: Did you have the problem before you installed the nvidia driver?

Comment: No. It was a brand new install and everything was working perfectly. I've googled around a little bit and this seems to be a common sort of problem after people install nvidia drivers on Debian-based OSes. However this time none of the traditional fixes worked. I believe things would change if I downgraded from nvidia-390.

Comment: Your workaround looks to me as your problem is with system Dee.  Wouldn't touch it with a stick but perhaps there's a "wants" wanting in graphical.target.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me after upgrading gdm3 (and in the process reconfiguring systemd). It was working before with the same nvidia-390 driver, which was not touched in the process.

Since downgrading gdm3 did not help, I used Ruan's solution for a little while before reverting back to search for a better solution. I still haven't found one, but realized that changing to another TTY and immediately changing back to TTY1 (or whatever is your graphical TTY) helps for me. Sometimes this has to be repeated a few times, but eventually it will work (at least for me it does).

So hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Wait a little to see if it worked, otherwise repeat.

I know that this is a hack rather than a real solution, but it's an immediate aid if you don't want to tamper with systemd's default target.

Comment: How many times are we talking? I'm in the same position, but I never saw this working.